A scrambled word which can't be easily guessed without all of its letters
I'm looking for a word with n letters that cannot be easily guessed given any n-1 of its letters.
The word should also not have any anagrams - once you know all n letters, you can determine the word uniquely.
For example, the word AND cannot be easily guessed if you only have A N, A D or D N.
What other words have this property? I am looking for high values of n, and approximate fits are fine for larger n (perhaps if you get some specific combination of letters you can guess it but in most cases you can't).
The context is a scavenger hunt - teams will be exploring a space and finding letters from the word in a random order, with the winners being the first to guess the word.
I'd like to make it as difficult as possible to guess the word without having found all of the letters.
The best answer is the longest word which can't be uniquely guessed from any n-1 letters in the word, or n points minus half a point for each combination of n-1 letters which can be used to guess the word.

Are teams limited in how many times they can guess the word?

I hope the participants don't see this page.

@xnor good question, I'd probably limit it to one guess per minute or something. Basically if the guess is wrong I'll tell them to go back and check their letters

By the way, if this is a game played by humans, you need to try to have both the correct guess and the incorrect guesses be decently-well-known words.

Why do you believe that the word AND has this property? You seem to be following from a false premise. If someone told me to guess a three letter word where two letters were known as AN, I am certain I would say AND.

@ubadub sure, you might guess and if you know AN, but it could be tan, ant, nap, any, can... If you get one guess your chances aren't high. Compare it to the letters GGS - the only word you'll guess is eggs

@base12 or GIGS or GAGS... (but I do get your point)

There might be an interesting version of this puzzle where the contestants know the requirement that it's a word which can't be guessed based on any n-1 letters.

@base12 I see that we are interpreting this question differently, possibly because it is poorly worded. To me, "CAN'T" implies impossibility. You might guess incorrectly, but that doesn't mean it's impossible. Though I see now the body does clarify they mean "cannot be easily guessed", so I should have read closer; the title is still misleading, though.

YAWL (word list)
Using Yet Another Word List (YAWL), there are two 13-letter words that work:
eternisations
-a: {intersections,overinsistent,retentionists}
-e: {strontianites}
-i: {antiestrogens,fenestrations,presentations}
-n: {desertisation,disorientates,etherisations}
-o: {intricateness}
-r: {necessitation,spontaneities}
-s: {eternizations,intenerations,reinfestation}
-t: {antirecession,containerises}

narcotisation
-a: {contristation}
-c: {notarizations}
-i: {contaminators,translocation}
-n: {factorisation,ratiocinators}
-o: {antiromantics}
-r: {cantonisation}
-s: {fractionation,narcotization,ratiocination}
-t: {carbonisation}

I put a list of 9-letter-or-longer words here.
Common words
using the most common 50,000 words, we get a few 9-letter words:
assertion        YAWL_anagrams: {arsonites,notarises,rosinates,senoritas}
-a: {investors}
-e: {arsonists,croissant}
-i: {ancestors,masterson,resonates,transpose}
-n: {asteroids}
-o: {asserting,canisters,resistant,streisand,tardiness}
-r: {cessation,sensation}
-s: {creations,patronise,reactions,relations}
-t: {scenarios}

canisters        YAWL_anagrams: {scenarist}
-a: {sincerest}
-c: {asserting,assertion,resistant,streisand,tardiness}
-e: {croissant}
-i: {ancestors,snatchers}
-n: {staircase}
-r: {cessation,distances,incessant,instances,semantics}
-s: {ascertain,creations,interacts,miscreant,reactions}
-t: {caressing,craziness,increases,scenarios}

cessation        YAWL_anagrams: {canoeists,sonicates}
-a: {consisted}
-c: {assertion,sensation}
-e: {croissant,sanctions}
-i: {ancestors}
-n: {associate}
-o: {canisters,distances,incessant,instances,semantics}
-s: {coastline,creations,reactions,tenacious}
-t: {ascension,scenarios}

estranged        YAWL_anagrams: {}
-a: {deserting}
-d: {generates,greatness,sergeants,teenagers}
-e: {strangled}
-g: {tradesmen}
-n: {staggered,tragedies}
-r: {designate}
-s: {generated}
-t: {endangers,gardeners,gendarmes,renegades}

inserting        YAWL_anagrams: {sintering}
-e: {sprinting,straining,stringing}
-g: {insertion}
-i: {insurgent,resenting,stringent}
-n: {intrigues,resisting}
-r: {enlisting,ingesting,ingestion,investing,listening}
-s: {interning,retaining,reuniting,tinkering}
-t: {resigning}

insertion        YAWL_anagrams: {}
-e: {intrusion,santorini}
-i: {innermost,inventors,neutrinos,serotonin}
-n: {interiors,seniority}
-o: {inserting}
-r: {ingestion}
-s: {rendition}
-t: {inversion}

repressed        YAWL_anagrams: {derepress}
-d: {preserves}
-e: {pressured}
-p: {deserters}
-r: {depressed,depresses,expressed,speedster}
-s: {preserved}

retaining        YAWL_anagrams: {}
-a: {inserting,interning,reuniting,tinkering}
-e: {rationing,straining,urinating}
-g: {itinerant}
-i: {argentina,argentine,parenting,tangerine}
-n: {originate}
-r: {detaining}
-t: {ingrained,regaining,remaining}

I put a list of 7-letter-or-longer words here.

And those two 13-letter words have 10 common letters.

This is great. Is there a subset of YAWL that restricts to more commonly known words? I'd be interested to see how much your list of solutions shrinks if the words must be used with a certain frequency (or some metric that makes sense)

Great answer! +1 @base12 I think the linked list by Tom here will lead you to what you need, there are several examples in the 10-11 length range which I would consider as commonly known and where removing a letter links to commonly known words.

@hexomino I've looked through the list but many of the words would be pretty obscure. I didn't see an example where both the word itself and at least one alternative for each missing letter was common. Which is why I'm wondering about a resource that quantifies how common the words are so we could decisively whittle the big list down

I have a 10-letter word that might work for you:

 CONTAINERS

Here are examples of words it could be if one letter is missing

 ONTAINERS --> RESONATING
 CNTAINERS --> TRANSIENCE
 COTAINERS --> CREMATIONS
 CONAINERS --> COARSENING
 CONTINERS --> CENTURIONS
 CONTANERS --> CONVERSANT
 CONTAIERS --> ACCRETIONS
 CONTAINRS --> CONSTRAINT
 CONTAINES --> SANCTIONED
 CONTAINER --> CONCERTINA

In the comments, WOWOW has pointed out a valid anagram of the word

 CRENATIONS

In that case another possible example is:

 INTERCEDES

Removing one letter

 NTERCEDES --> PRECEDENTS
 ITERCEDES --> DISCREETER
 INERCEDES --> WIDESCREEN
 INTRCEDES --> DIRECTNESS
 INTECEDES --> CENTIPEDES
 INTEREDES --> DETERMINES
 INTERCDES --> IRIDESCENT
 INTERCEES --> EPICENTRES
 INTERCEDS --> CHRISTENED
 INTERCEDE --> INTERCEDED


I think crenations is an anagram

@WOWOW ah okay, this is a word I have not come across, I might have another example that will work

Erfrpgvbaf is an anagram of frpergvbaf.

@WOWOW I have now replaced it with a different possibility, can you check that too?

Couldn't find any anagrams :) There might be an anagram but I don't think so

Your answer has 3 copies of the letter E, and for each you have provided a different candidate word when leaving out such an E. Assuming you searched by computer, does the program/tool insist on distinct candidates even with the same missing letter, and if so, could there be better solution if you drop this unnecessary requirement?

Good finds. I'll wait some time to see if anyone can beat 10

@JaapScherphuis I did search by computer but did not insist on distinct candidates. It just happened that, for this example, there were several after removing an E so I included different ones.
